# C# Windows Form - Anchor

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two elements in the form, two GridViews.
Both of them are aligned horizontally at the same level.
When my form is resizing, I want both of them to change their width/ height according to the form size. 
The problem is, if I try to anchor them, they kinda overlap at some point and I want to avoid that.

My question is, can I anchor one Grid View to the other Grid View and not to the form?

A solution can be a TabelLayoutLabel, but i don't really want to use this.

Comment: So what exactly is the layout behaviour you want? Do you want them to both take up half the screen? A screenshot or two would help in seeing your form and what you want. You will almost certainly need to do this by handling the SizeChanged event, as this is beyond what anchor can handle.

Comment: Handling the `Resize` event of the form is also an option.

Comment: Having to set the form's MinimumSize property is entirely normal.

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot of what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is, can I anchor one Grid View to the other Grid View and not to the form?

no you cannot, and if you could that would be bad practice.
the anchor property description by microsoft:

> Gets or sets the edges of the **container** to which a control is bound
> and determines how a control is resized with its parent.

a dataGridView is not a container it's a control.

it sounds like you should use a table layout panel, that would give you the best results.

search for it in the Toolbox:

[image]

make sure you set its property to Dock = fill, where ever you want, and
,
next. in the property of the table view, you enter Edit Rows And Columns

[image]

and set each column to the percentage that you desire

[image]
add your grids to each column,
and set each one's 'Dock' property to Fill, and there you go

[image]
[image]

you can undock the tableLayoutPanel and change its size,

Hope that was helpful

Comment: Thank you! Even though i didn't wanted to use TableLayoutPanel, it seems like the best solution and i will use this. Thank you again!

Comment: @Silviu, great, glad I could help. you can Accept my answer if you think it was helpful.

Comment: Done. I am new on the stackoverflow. :D I think you meant to press that 'correct sign', right?

Comment: @Silviu yes exactly